# Do not hide modal while clicking Left/Right in overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need this modal to not hide when you click in the overlay area (right or left button).

Example: when your click right button in overlay area, hide the modal.
The modal do not hide when your clicked in overlay, something clicked in "closed button".

Thank you!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
  jQuery('#popup-container a.close').click(function(){
      jQuery('#popup-container').fadeOut();
      jQuery('#active-popup').fadeOut();
  });
  
  var visits = jQuery.cookie('visits') || 0;
  visits++;
  
  jQuery.cookie('visits', visits, { expires: 1, path: '/' });
    
  console.debug(jQuery.cookie('visits'));
    
  if ( jQuery.cookie('visits') > 1 ) {
    jQuery('#active-popup').hide();
    jQuery('#popup-container').hide();
  } else {
      var pageHeight = jQuery(document).height();
      jQuery('<div id="active-popup"></div>').insertBefore('body');
      jQuery('#active-popup').css("height", pageHeight);
      jQuery('#popup-container').show();
  }

  if (jQuery.cookie('noShowWelcome')) { jQuery('#popup-container').hide(); jQuery('#active-popup').hide(); }
}); 

jQuery(document).mouseup(function(e){
  var container = jQuery('#popup-container');
  
  if( !container.is(e.target)&& container.has(e.target).length === 0)
  {
    container.fadeOut();
    jQuery('#active-popup').fadeOut();
  }

});
```

```css
/* Fullscreen overlay for modal background */
#active-popup {
  background-color: rgba(52,73,94, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  heighT: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

/* Modal container */
#popup-container {
  width: 45%;
  height: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 28%;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  background: #E74C3C;
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#popup-window { position: relative; }

.modal-content h1,
.modal-content p { color: #fff; }

.modal-content p { padding: 20% 5% 0 5%; }

/* Close button */
#popup-container a.close {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: -15px;
  right: -7px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 6px;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E74C3C;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>



<div id="popup-container">
  <a class="close">x</a>
    <div id="popup-window">
      <div class="splash-bg">
        <a href="#" class="your-class"></a>
      <h1><a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Modal/">Modal</a> Popup Window</h1>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of it your overlay should hide, if this piece of code is fixed to be:

```
jQuery(document).mouseup(function(e){
  var container = jQuery('#popup-container');
  var activePopup = jQuery('#active-popup');

  if(container.is(e.target) && !activePopup.container.is(e.target) && activePopup.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    container.fadeOut();
    activePopup.fadeOut();
  }

});
```

So if you don't want the container to close model, remove above code.

Comment: Did that work? I hadn't tested it really. Good to know :)